# How can i auto align html in "Edit as HTML" in Google Chrome Dev Tools

Tags: html, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Is there any option to auto align html in "Edit as HTML" in Chrome Dev Tools? I am asking about it because i want to for example wrap code with additional `<div>`:

[image: Code i want to wrap with additional div]

When i right click div with class title and select "Edit as HTML" that will show up:

[image: Code allowed to edit]

Is there any option to deal with that mess and align these tags?

Comment: Nope. Sounds like a good feature request for https://crbug.com

Comment: Thank You, done ;) https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=769266

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I got that answer from crbug.com:

> This is because we parse the HTML and map it to the raw innerHTML of
>   the element. This means that if the element was created or sent with
>   strange formatting it'll preserve that formatting. In your case it may
>   look like it's not working as expected, but if the user set the
>   innerHTML to some strange stuff and we formatted it for them, they may
>   feel like it was not working as expected.
>           I am going to mark as wont-fix since this is intended behavior.

So there is no hope to improve something in that manner :-(